How to make Nunjucks render a file without parsing, in Hexo
I am using Hexo to write a blog and I am using a custom JS file. The content '{{' appears inside, causing it to be parsed by the template engine Nunjucks. How can I ignore this JS file? Now, as soon as I build it, an error message 'expected variable end' appears
exclude: /source/css/.js
ignore: /source/css/.js
Not effective
